# Adding tensorflow properties into Config class

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory, config

I have a Config class called BalloonConfig and it inherits the properties of Config (config.py). In my main.py file -

```html
class BalloonConfig(Config):
    """Configuration for training on the toy  dataset.
    Derives from the base Config class and overrides some values.
    """
    # Give the configuration a recognizable name
    NAME = "Bubbles"

    # We use a GPU with 12GB memory, which can fit two images.
    # Adjust down if you use a smaller GPU.
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1

    GPU_COUNT = 1
    # Number of classes (including background)
    NUM_CLASSES = 1 + 1  # Background + baloon

    # Number of training steps per epoch
    STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 1000

    # Skip detections with < 90% confidence
    DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE = 0.7

    LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001
```

and in my config.py I have

```html
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


# Base Configuration Class
# Don't use this class directly. Instead, sub-class it and override
# the configurations you need to change.

class Config():
    """Base configuration class. For custom configurations, create a
    sub-class that inherits from this one and override properties
    that need to be changed.
    """
    # Name the configurations. For example, 'COCO', 'Experiment 3', ...etc.
    # Useful if your code needs to do things differently depending on which
    # experiment is running.
    NAME = None  # Override in sub-classes

    # NUMBER OF GPUs to use. For CPU training, use 1
    GPU_COUNT = 1

    # Number of images to train with on each GPU. A 12GB GPU can typically
    # handle 2 images of 1024x1024px.
    # Adjust based on your GPU memory and image sizes. Use the highest
    # number that your GPU can handle for best performance.
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1

    # Number of training steps per epoch
    # This doesn't need to match the size of the training set. Tensorboard
    # updates are saved at the end of each epoch, so setting this to a
    # smaller number means getting more frequent TensorBoard updates.
    # Validation stats are also calculated at each epoch end and they
    # might take a while, so don't set this too small to avoid spending
    # a lot of time on validation stats.
    STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 1000

    # Number of validation steps to run at the end of every training epoch.
    # A bigger number improves accuracy of validation stats, but slows
    # down the training.
    VALIDATION_STEPS = 50

    # Backbone network architecture
    # Supported values are: resnet50, resnet101
    BACKBONE = "resnet101"

    # The strides of each layer of the FPN Pyramid. These values
    # are based on a Resnet101 backbone.
    BACKBONE_STRIDES = [4, 8, 16, 32, 64]

    # Number of classification classes (including background)
    NUM_CLASSES = 1  # Override in sub-classes

    # Length of square anchor side in pixels
    RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES = (32, 64, 128, 256, 512)

    # Ratios of anchors at each cell (width/height)
    # A value of 1 represents a square anchor, and 0.5 is a wide anchor
    RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS = [0.5, 1, 2]

    # Anchor stride
    # If 1 then anchors are created for each cell in the backbone feature map.
    # If 2, then anchors are created for every other cell, and so on.
    RPN_ANCHOR_STRIDE = 1

    # Non-max suppression threshold to filter RPN proposals.
    # You can increase this during training to generate more propsals.
    RPN_NMS_THRESHOLD = 0.7

    # How many anchors per image to use for RPN training
    RPN_TRAIN_ANCHORS_PER_IMAGE = 256

    # ROIs kept after non-maximum supression (training and inference)
    POST_NMS_ROIS_TRAINING = 2000
    POST_NMS_ROIS_INFERENCE = 1000

    # If enabled, resizes instance masks to a smaller size to reduce
    # memory load. Recommended when using high-resolution images.
    USE_MINI_MASK = True
    MINI_MASK_SHAPE = (56, 56)  # (height, width) of the mini-mask

    # Input image resizing
    # Generally, use the "square" resizing mode for training and inferencing
    # and it should work well in most cases. In this mode, images are scaled
    # up such that the small side is = IMAGE_MIN_DIM, but ensuring that the
    # scaling doesn't make the long side > IMAGE_MAX_DIM. Then the image is
    # padded with zeros to make it a square so multiple images can be put
    # in one batch.
    # Available resizing modes:
    # none:   No resizing or padding. Return the image unchanged.
    # square: Resize and pad with zeros to get a square image
    #         of size [max_dim, max_dim].
    # pad64:  Pads width and height with zeros to make them multiples of 64.
    #         If IMAGE_MIN_DIM or IMAGE_MIN_SCALE are not None, then it scales
    #         up before padding. IMAGE_MAX_DIM is ignored in this mode.
    #         The multiple of 64 is needed to ensure smooth scaling of feature
    #         maps up and down the 6 levels of the FPN pyramid (2**6=64).
    # crop:   Picks random crops from the image. First, scales the image based
    #         on IMAGE_MIN_DIM and IMAGE_MIN_SCALE, then picks a random crop of
    #         size IMAGE_MIN_DIM x IMAGE_MIN_DIM. Can be used in training only.
    #         IMAGE_MAX_DIM is not used in this mode.
    IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE = "square"
    IMAGE_MIN_DIM = 800
    IMAGE_MAX_DIM = 1024
    # Minimum scaling ratio. Checked after MIN_IMAGE_DIM and can force further
    # up scaling. For example, if set to 2 then images are scaled up to double
    # the width and height, or more, even if MIN_IMAGE_DIM doesn't require it.
    # Howver, in 'square' mode, it can be overruled by IMAGE_MAX_DIM.
    IMAGE_MIN_SCALE = 0

    # Image mean (RGB)
    MEAN_PIXEL = np.array([123.7, 116.8, 103.9])

    # Number of ROIs per image to feed to classifier/mask heads
    # The Mask RCNN paper uses 512 but often the RPN doesn't generate
    # enough positive proposals to fill this and keep a positive:negative
    # ratio of 1:3. You can increase the number of proposals by adjusting
    # the RPN NMS threshold.
    TRAIN_ROIS_PER_IMAGE = 200

    # Percent of positive ROIs used to train classifier/mask heads
    ROI_POSITIVE_RATIO = 0.33

    # Pooled ROIs
    POOL_SIZE = 7
    MASK_POOL_SIZE = 14

    # Shape of output mask
    # To change this you also need to change the neural network mask branch
    MASK_SHAPE = [28, 28]

    # Maximum number of ground truth instances to use in one image
    MAX_GT_INSTANCES = 100

    # Bounding box refinement standard deviation for RPN and final detections.
    RPN_BBOX_STD_DEV = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2])
    BBOX_STD_DEV = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2])

    # Max number of final detections
    DETECTION_MAX_INSTANCES = 100

    # Minimum probability value to accept a detected instance
    # ROIs below this threshold are skipped
    DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE = 0.7

    # Non-maximum suppression threshold for detection
    DETECTION_NMS_THRESHOLD = 0.3

    # Learning rate and momentum
    # The Mask RCNN paper uses lr=0.02, but on TensorFlow it causes
    # weights to explode. Likely due to differences in optimzer
    # implementation.
    LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
    LEARNING_MOMENTUM = 0.9

    # Weight decay regularization
    WEIGHT_DECAY = 0.0001

    # Use RPN ROIs or externally generated ROIs for training
    # Keep this True for most situations. Set to False if you want to train
    # the head branches on ROI generated by code rather than the ROIs from
    # the RPN. For example, to debug the classifier head without having to
    # train the RPN.
    USE_RPN_ROIS = True

    # Train or freeze batch normalization layers
    #     None: Train BN layers. This is the normal mode
    #     False: Freeze BN layers. Good when using a small batch size
    #     True: (don't use). Set layer in training mode even when inferencing
    TRAIN_BN = False  # Defaulting to False since batch size is often small

    # Gradient norm clipping
    GRADIENT_CLIP_NORM = 5.0

    def __init__(self):
        """Set values of computed attributes."""
        # Effective batch size
        self.BATCH_SIZE = self.IMAGES_PER_GPU * self.GPU_COUNT

        # Input image size
        if self.IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE == "crop":
            self.IMAGE_SHAPE = np.array([self.IMAGE_MIN_DIM, self.IMAGE_MIN_DIM, 3])
        else:
            self.IMAGE_SHAPE = np.array([self.IMAGE_MAX_DIM, self.IMAGE_MAX_DIM, 3])

        # Image meta data length
        # See compose_image_meta() for details
        self.IMAGE_META_SIZE = 1 + 3 + 3 + 4 + 1 + self.NUM_CLASSES

    def display(self):
        """Display Configuration values."""
        print("\nConfigurations:")
        for a in dir(self):
            if not a.startswith("__") and not callable(getattr(self, a)):
                print("{:30} {}".format(a, getattr(self, a)))
        print("\n")
```

I will start running the script in my main.py using argpars

```html
    # Configurations
    if args.command == "train":
        config = BalloonConfig()
        
    # Create model
    if args.command == "train":
        # print('test')
        model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="training", config=config,
                                  model_dir=args.logs)
```

and it will create the model and assign the config file to BalloonConfig(). But I found out that the GPU memory is not enough and the training fails to start. After some researching, I came across something called GPU growth inside tensorflow and it can solve my out of memory problem -

```html
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

However, I do not know how to implement it into my code as i cannot assign my config file to tf.ConfigProto() as I have already assigned it to BalloonConfig(). So may I know how to set the gpu_options.allow_growth inside my scripts? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is might be facing the same problem and wants to add in `config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True`, I managed to solved the problem by adding the 3 lines:

```
conf = tf.ConfigProto()
conf.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
session = tf.Session(config=conf)
```

right after the importing of tensorflow (import tensorflow as tf) in the file whereby training or inference is done, and then the gpu allow growth option will be activated right after. Not too sure why it works but hope it helps anyone that needs it!

Answer (score 0):

If `tf.session` can understand your `BalloonConfig`, it suffices to just add the property to your config:

```py
    # Configurations
    if args.command == "train":
        config = BalloonConfig()
        config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
```

If not, you should define your `BalloonConfig` class like this (and then do the above):

```py
class BalloonConfig(tf.ConfigProto):
#...
```

Comment: Hi @ibarrond, thanks for your reply, i first tried to add config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True, but it states that the BallonConfig object does not have attribute gpu options. Hence like what u said, i tried to inherit the tf.ConfigProto properties by adding it inside the BalloonConfig class - 
class BalloonConfig(tf.ConfigProto):
#...

But it still throws out the error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bubble.py", line 61, in <module>
    class BalloonConfig(tf.ConfigProto):
TypeError: A Message class can only inherit from Message

Comment: How were you applying the `Config` class you present above?

Comment: I changed it from class BalloonConfig(Config): to class BalloonConfig(tf.ConfigProto): - so will that mean I have not applied the Config class to my BalloonConfig class? How should I do it if that is the case? @ibarrond

Comment: I mean before any of my suggestions.

Comment: in my main.py (or rather bubble.py) file, i have inheritted the Config class (from config.py) inside the BalloonConfig class by defining class BalloonConfig(Config): . Not too sure if that was what you were asking. @ibarrond

Comment: Now that I see it, I believe there are two different `config` objects: One for the model (your `BalloonConfig`) and one for the tf.Session (the `tf.ConfigProto`). You should keep them separate!

Comment: I see.. but i'm still confused on how to set the session or modify the session. I dont seem to find any tf.session anywhere, so i cant add it the tf.ConfigProto... @ibarrond